# select 1 line per category based on number

Tags: python

I have list of 5 columns with in the 5th column a list of numbers, and in column 1 a group identifier. There are 500 lines in total but only 24 groups.

What I want is to select only one line from each group identifier which has the smallest number in column 5.

E.g.

```
sheet= """ 
cmn1\tcmn2\tcmn3\tcmn4\tcmn5
rob\t45\tfoo\tbar\t0.0001
Steve\t32\tfoo\tspam\t0.01
rob\t45\tbar\tfoo\t0.0000001
Steve\t32\tfoo\tbar\t0.1"""
```

This is the desired outcome:

```
cmn1\tcmn2\tcmn3\tcmn4\tcmn5
Steve\t32\tfoo\tspam\t.01
rob\t45\tbar\tfoo\t0.0000001
```

I got my fields in list per line but am stuck on how to select the line with smallest number in parts[4]

```
for line in sheet:
     line = sheet.strip().split("\n")

parts = []

for part in line: 
      parts = []
      parts = part.split("\t")
      print parts [0], parts [1], parts[2], parts[3], parts[4]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sheet= """ cmn1 cmn2 cmn3 cmn4 cmn5
rob  45   foo  bar  0.0001
Steve 32  foo  spam 0.01
rob   45  bar  foo  0.0000001
Steve 32  foo  bar  0.1"""

from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
spl = sheet.splitlines()
header = spl[0]
# iterate over all lines except header
for line in spl[1:]:
    # split once on whitespace using name as the key 
    name = line.split(None,1)[0]
    # append each line to our list of values
    d[name].append(line)

# get min of each line in our values based on the last float value
for v in d.values():
    print(min(v,key=lambda x: float(x.split()[-1])))

Steve 32  foo  spam 0.01
rob   45  bar  foo  0.0000001
```

If order matters you can use and OrderedDict ad also check as you go:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict()
spl = sheet.splitlines()
header = spl[0]
for line in spl[1:]:
    # unpack five elements after splitting
    # using name as key and f to cast to float and compare
    name, _, _, _, f = line.split()
    # if key exists compare float value to current float value
    # keeping or replacing the values based on the outcome
    if name in d and float(d[name].split()[-1]) > float(f):
        d[name] = line
    # else if first time seeing name just add it
    elif name not in d:
        d[name] = line

print(header)
for v in d.values():
    print(v)

cmn1 cmn2 cmn3 cmn4 cmn5
rob   45  bar  foo  0.0000001
Steve 32  foo  spam 0.01
```

Using you edited lines you can see the outout is not changed, it will be exactly as it was originally:

```
for v in d.values():
    print(repr(v))

'rob\t45\tbar\tfoo\t0.0000001'
'Steve\t32\tfoo\tspam\t0.01
```

Comment: Thanks. Think i understand it. Only the `print("{}.` -- what do the `{}` stand for ?

Comment: @oaklander114, I was going to print some extra data so I was going to use `str.format` but I just removed it.

Comment: I see. Problem is only that I want the Cmns to be delimited in some way other than with white space.. How could I e.g. put some "\t" in between the fields of the line?

Comment: you can just `str.replace `, `print("foo ".replace(" ","\t\tfoo"))`, is this data coming from and going to a csv file?

Comment: I adjusted my question to reflect the type of file. I don't really understand how to deal with this based on your last comment. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @oaklander114, we are not changing the original line at all we just keep the line with the lowest float value so any tabs are atill going to be there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72870/discussion-between-oaklander114-and-padraic-cunningham).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to grouping your split lines based on first item then use `min` function with a proper `key` to select the desire line:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> s=sorted((line.split() for line in sheet.strip().split('\n')[1:]),key=itemgetter(0))
>>> [' '.join(min(g,key=lambda x:float(x[4]))) for _,g in groupby(s,itemgetter(0))]
['Steve 32 foo spam 0.01', 'rob 45 bar foo 0.0000001']
```

Comment: Much  more succinct than mine.  I didn't know about this function.

Comment: n log n as opposed to linear

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yeah! but as an alternative this way is pretty :)

Comment: No real advantage space wise as you create another list and worse complexity,  this would also fail in many cases as you are comparing strings not floats

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to store all the lines for each unique column 1:

```
sheet= """cmn1\tcmn2\tcmn3\tcmn4\tcmn5
rob\t45\tfoo\tbar\t0.0001
Steve\t32\tfoo\tspam\t0.01
rob\t45\tbar\tfoo\t0.0000001
Steve\t32\tfoo\tbar\t0.1"""

grouped = {}
for line in sheet.split('\n')[1:]:
  parts = line.split('\t')
  print (line)
  # Parse the numbers into numerical types
  typed = (parts[0], int(parts[1]), parts[2], parts[3], float(parts[4]))
  #Add the typed list of values into a list stored in our dict
  if parts[0] in grouped.keys():
    grouped[parts[0]].append(typed) 
  else:
    grouped[parts[0]] = [typed]

#Now you can go through all the keys in the dict and select the smallest  
smallest_per_group = []
for key in grouped:
  lines = grouped[key]
  # using the 'key' parameter tells Python to give us the line with the smallest 5th column
  smallest = min(lines, key=lambda x:x[4])
  smallest_per_group.append(smallest)
```

Comment: line 3 gives error: ` 'list' object has no attribute 'split' `

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit hasty; I wasn't really paying attention to the way we were getting input.  I've edited it and it now should work.